# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated in min.js 1.6.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, kohana-3.2

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

```
****// Open the socket
                    // Passing null username, generates a login popup on Opera (#2865)
                    if ( s.username ) {
                        xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password );
                    } else {
                        xhr.open( s.type, s.url, s.async );
                    }****
```

How to solved this?

Comment: Don't use synchronous AJAX? jQuery won't unless you tell it to with `async: false`.

Comment: Are you trying to execute the ajax call before the page has fully loaded?